# How to send parameters with http request

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I am building an app using node.js and am using the `request` package to make requests. I am trying to pass data to my server API to return all orders - my question is how can I send parameters as part of my request? My code so far:

```
function callback(error, response, body) {
        console.log(body); //returns empty; should return array of orders
        res.render('../views/orders');
    }

    var options = {
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/orders',
        headers: {
            host: 'localhost:3000',
            connection: 'close',
            cookie: cookieText
        },
        data: { //data and company_id are parameters I want to pass
            email: 'abc123@gmail.com',
            company_id: 'secretcompanyid'
        }
    };

    request(options, callback);
```

In my code, `email` and `company_id` are the parameters my server side API needs. However, the current request is not returning any data. When I console.log the parameters on the server side, it returns empty therefore I think the issue is how I am passing parameters to the server. Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this since its a GET request:

```
function callback(error, response, body) {
        console.log(body); //returns empty; should return array of orders
        res.render('../views/orders');
    }

    var options = {
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/orders',
        headers: {
            host: 'localhost:3000',
            connection: 'close',
            cookie: cookieText
        },
        qs: { //data and company_id are parameters I want to pass
            email: 'abc123@gmail.com',
            company_id: 'secretcompanyid'
        }
    };

    request(options, callback);
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried that but the server api is still returning empty when i `console.log(req.body) // returns {}`

Comment: Is this a post or get request?

Comment: It's a get request - i need the server to return data

Comment: do you get the proper response when you replace your url with: `url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/orders?email=abc@gmail.com&company_id=dasda',`